# How to filter out sales to find customers who have not purchased in the last 2 years

Tags: oracle, sum

What I am trying to accomplish is to find all the customers who have sales in the past but have not purchased from us in the last 2 years `(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR)`

Here is my code currently.

```
select invc.company
 , invc.customer_id
 , to_char(invc.invdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date
 , invc.name
 , invc.address1
 , invc.address2
 , invc.city
 , invc.state
 , invc.zip_code
 , invc.country
 , invc.region_code
 , invc.site
 , sum(invc.sales) as SlsAmnt
from ifsinfo.hb_invoicing_all invc
where **THIS IS THE PART IM STUCK AT**
group by invc.company
           , invc.customer_id
           , invc.creation_date
           , invc.name
           , invc.address1
           , invc.address2
           , invc.city
           , invc.state
           , invc.zip_code
           , invc.country
           , invc.region_code
           , invc.site
```

I am basically looking for a query that will return a list of customers who haven't purchased from us in 2 years or more.

`SUM(SALES) = 0` within last 2 years+

Comment: Is it possible to have Sales with a zero or less amount? If not can't you just ensure their ID is not in the sales table with a date more recent than 2 years ago?

Comment: It is NOT possible. That is a great point Dave. Thank you for that input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sales in the last two years means:

```
having max(invc.invdate) < (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR)
```